# case_when function to satisfy all exact constraints

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with the case_when() function in R because I'm handling all exceptions in a certain piece of code. My question is rather simple I think, but I'm not sure how to achieve it. With the case_when() function multiple arguments (like in any other statement) can be taken into account. Given the following example;

```
a <- "aap"

b <- case_when(str_count(a,"a") > 1 ~ 1,
               str_count(a,"a") > 1 & str_count(a,"p") >= 1 ~ 2)
```

I want to return the value 2, but because the argument of return value 1 is also satisfied, it returns 1 instead of 2. Is there an easy workaround for this? Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You could invert your conditions. Also, here your second condition is not satisfied (there is one p in aap, not >1).
If you type :

```
b <- case_when(str_count(a,"a") > 1 & str_count(a,"p") >= 1 ~ 2,str_count(a,"a") > 1 ~ 1)
```

It indeed returns 2.

Comment: The problem is that I already have 7 sperate cases and I expect to end with around 15. Some of which are very similar. For that reason just switching them around will unfortunately not work for me. I've edited my question, you where right about the >= but it will still return 1 if the search for the "p" is the second argument.

Comment: Then please provide a larger reproducible example to help us help you.

Comment: I am reading PDF files within a much larger script, it's not easy to extract that piece of code and make it so that it is reproducible here. If like you and @mrGrumble say the case_when always takes the first true, I guess I just have to write out all the exceptional rules. My question only is how to return 2 because it contains "a" and "p" instead of 1, but I guess I than just have to define that the script may not return 1 if there is any "p" in the string.. Thanks anyway for the insight

Comment: You don't need to provide your own data to build a reproducible example, just something that helps solve the question. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Nonetheless: I don't understand why switching terms would not solve your problem, but otherwise yes, if your statements are specific enough, with more conditions, it could do the job. Just keep in mind, as detailed by MrGumble, that it will stop when one condition is TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

`case_when` stops at the first `TRUE` condition. This is also why an `else` condition (or "default", if you will) occurs lastly:

```
case_when(
  a ~ 'a is true and nothing else matters',
  b ~ 'a was not true, but b is, and nothing else matters',
  TRUE ~ 'none of the above was true'
)
```

Swap the two statements and you should be good.

Comment: The problem is that I already have 7 sperate cases and I expect to end with around 15. Some of which are very similar. For that reason just switching them around will unfortunately not work for me

Comment: With 15 cases I suspect your issue is quite different from the posted question; i.e. why even use `case_when`? Regardless of your approach, with 15 cases you need to be very susinct in which order you test things. Perhaps an entirely different approach might be better.

Comment: Hi mrGrumble, see my comment @Mata, I am reading PDF's and want to automate it. I want to catch all the variations of the format of a certain piece of text the PDF file. This piece of text is only 6 lines of max. 2 words but the exact location of the information can be in different places, thats why I thought the case_when function would be helpful. But also like I said in my other comment to Mata, I guess I just have to be more precise in my description of each case. Thanks for the information and comments though : )

Comment: No worries. Seems your otherwise concise and nicely put question simply didn't represent the issue you are looking at, so the answers weren't applicable. Mark any question as preferred answer, and ask a new question that better reflects your issue (i.e. the text consists of multiple lines, each of 1-2 words).